# Query optimisation for order BY DESC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Total number of records in table "taking" = 12 000.

I have below query in which only need 10 records which is recently or last added records. So I apply OrderBy desc but when I apply DESC using ORDER BY on bid then it will hang and query will return output in 15 mins for 10 records.

```
 SELECT taking.BId ,taking.calledDate Called,taking.calleduser Caller,taking.callerNotes,taking.Title,
taking.FName,taking.ScName,taking.takingPhase, Training.TName,
taking.TrDate,taking.SubmitDateTime, TrLocation.TrLocation trTrl,
taking.STATUS,taking.DelegNum, taking.Tel, taking.Email,taking.Notes
FROM Taking taking
LEFT JOIN training Training ON taking.Training = Training.TId
LEFT JOIN confirmation ON taking.Bid = confirmation.Bid
LEFT JOIN TrLocation ON taking.TrLocation = TrLocation.TrLId
LEFT JOIN Invoice ON taking.BId =Invoice.BId
LEFT JOIN couriertracking ON taking.BId = couriertracking.bId
LEFT JOIN SalesPerson ON taking.SId = SalesPerson.SId WHERE
taking.SubmitDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)  AND IFNULL(taking.SId,0) > 0
ORDER BY taking.BId DESC LIMIT 10
```

I tried Indexing at bid column but still query time is same. How can i optimise the query?

Comment: How many rows do you get, and how long does it take, if you remove `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

Comment: Thanks for replay, It will return around 11,533 records after removing ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are one of the last steps in SQL order of operations. Likely, your full resultset is being processed and then these last commands sorts and cuts off the resultset. Look into indexing the join fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have LEFT JOINs, and the LEFT JOIN can only add more rows, you can limit the number of rows returned from the `Taking` table with a subquery. Then only 10 rows need to be joined with the other tables. If any JOIN will add more rows, you can still use another LIMIT in the outer query.

```
SELECT
    taking.BId,taking.calledDate Called, taking.calleduser Caller,
    taking.callerNotes, taking.Title, taking.FName, taking.ScName,
    taking.takingPhase, Training.TName, taking.TrDate,
    taking.SubmitDateTime, TrLocation.TrLocation trTrl, taking.STATUS,
    taking.DelegNum, taking.Tel, taking.Email,taking.Notes
FROM (
    SELECT taking.*
    FROM Taking taking
    WHERE taking.SubmitDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
      AND taking.SId > 0
    ORDER BY taking.BId DESC
    LIMIT 10
) taking
LEFT JOIN training Training ON taking.Training = Training.TId
LEFT JOIN confirmation ON taking.Bid = confirmation.Bid
LEFT JOIN TrLocation ON taking.TrLocation = TrLocation.TrLId
LEFT JOIN Invoice ON taking.BId =Invoice.BId
LEFT JOIN couriertracking ON taking.BId = couriertracking.bId
LEFT JOIN SalesPerson ON taking.SId = SalesPerson.SId
ORDER BY taking.BId DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Note that `taking.SId > 0` has the same effect as `IFNULL(taking.SId,0) > 0` in the WHERE clause. Rows with `NULL` in `SId` will not match that condition.

However - You should still verify that you have indexes on every column which are used for the joins in every table. For this query you will need indexes on

- `Training.TId`
- `confirmation.Bid`
- `TrLocation.TrLId`
- `Invoice.BId`
- `couriertracking.bId`
- `SalesPerson.SId`

Some of them look like primary keys. If that's the case then you don't need to index them.

To find the best index for the `Taking` table is not that simple. But 12K rows is not that much. You should be fine just with an index on `SubmitDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments it works for me. Now query response in 6 milliseconds. Thank you So much.